# Visual studio 2008 html project documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i read a lot of threads on stackoverflow regarding the documentation production under visual studio.

i went on sandcastle website but i'm not sure it is what i'm looking for. I'm trying to produce a website msdn stile where my team can find project documentation. Visual studio allow to create xml files but next step still miss: creation of html structure from xml files.

any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandcastle is the Microsoft-made documentation generator, but you need a front end for it. I prefer DocProject myself:
[DocProject on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/DocProject)

It integrates into Visual Studio and lets you manipulate the output in a pretty reasonable manner. The output is supposed to be "MSDN style" and you get a couple of choices for themes. Unfortunately no choice for the awesome new "lightweight" theme.

The DocProject site has fairly thorough documentation and will walk you through everything.

Beware, the actual documentation generation operation is pretty resource heavy regardless of how you use Sandcastle.

Comment: You might also like to check out Sandcastle Help File Builder (also on codeplex: http://shfb.codeplex.com/) which gives reliable results - agreed that the first run of either of these takes a long time as references are loaded, etc.

Also, check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319632/docproject-vs-sandcastle-help-file-builder-gui

Comment: I should've mentioned SHFB, thanks for fixing my omission. Personally I prefer docproject myself, but in the end they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link : [C# XML Comments Let You Build Documentation Directly From Your Visual Studio .NET Source Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx)

Example of how the documentation will look with style
[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Bb986142.xmlcfig08%28en-us,MSDN.10%29.gif))</sub>